# Java, does not register user input at end of do-while loop

Tags: java, input, while-loop

I have this code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyAccount {
    public static double balance = 0.0;

    public static double deposit(double deposit){
        return balance += deposit;
    }
    //public void setBalance(double balance){
    //  this.balance = balance;
    //}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String redo = "";
        do{
        System.out.println("What do you want to do today?");
        String answer= in.nextLine();
        if(answer.equals("deposit")){
            System.out.println("How much do you want to deposit?");
            double money = in.nextDouble();
            deposit(money);
        }
        System.out.println("Your balance is " + balance);
        System.out.println("Anything else(Y or N)?");
        redo = in.nextLine().toUpperCase();
        } while(redo.equals("Y"));
    }
}
```

The program works just fine up until the end. If I deposit money into it and reach the line "Anything else(Y or N)?" I can not enter anything after; even though I have the `redo` String there.  Though if I don't deposit money, I can enter something for `redo` and can get the program to loop. How do I fix it so it loops even when I deposit something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is somewhat tricky. It's because after you call `in.nextDouble()`, the `\n` from the user is still in the input stream, such that `redo` will be equal to an empty String when you call `redo = in.nextLine().toUpperCase()`. To fix it, add `in.nextLine()` like so:

```
    if(answer.equals("deposit")){
        System.out.println("How much do you want to deposit?");
        double money = in.nextDouble();
        in.nextLine();
        deposit(money);
    }
```

Or another alternative is:

```
    if(answer.equals("deposit")){
        System.out.println("How much do you want to deposit?");
        double money = Double.parseDouble(in.nextLine());
        deposit(money);
    }
```